# pausing audio after setInterval

Tags: jquery, html

I am looking to stop the audio once a STOP button is clicked. the way i have it now only stops the audio for a moment then continues to play again.

Here is my code

```
let x = 500;

$("#buttonStart").click(()=>{
    setInterval(function() {$('audio')[0].play();}, x);
})

$("#buttonStop").click(()=>{
// I WANT TO STOP THE AUDIO COMPLETELY HERE     
    $('audio')[0].pause();

})
```

Comment: Why are you using `setInterval` at all? If anything, you should use `setTimeout` as that only runs once.

Answer (score 1):

try something like this

```
var task;

$("#buttonStart").click(()=>{
    task = setInterval(function() {$('audio')[0].play();}, x);
})

$("#buttonStop").click(()=>{
// I WANT TO STOP THE AUDIO COMPLETELY HERE     
    clearInterval(task);
})
```

Comment: ClearInterval is the right answer, but still doesn't explain why setInterval is being used at all. Is the audio playing on a loop?

Comment: I'm glad this solution worked!  Please take the time to mark this answer as the solution.  it helps users like myself to gain credibility and stackoverflow as a whole become better.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could have a public boolean that said if the music is supposed to be played or not.

```
var musicOn = false;
let x = 500;

$("#buttonStart").click(()=>{
    musicOn = true;
    setInterval(function() {
        if(musicOn==true){
            $('audio')[0].play();
        }, x);
    }
})

$("#buttonStop").click(()=>{
// I WANT TO STOP THE AUDIO COMPLETELY HERE     
    musicOn = false;
})
```

Maybe a lazy solution, but would definitely work

Comment: Your setInterval ends right after the if statement, should be 1 line lower ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can set your play interval to a variable, then when you click the STOP button, you can clear the interval with clearInterval.

```
  let x = 500;
  let playing;

  $("#buttonStart").click(()=>{
    playing = setInterval(function() {$('audio')[0].play();}, x);
  });

  $("#buttonStop").click(()=>{    
    clearInterval(playing);
  });
```